# How to change color of stroke

Tags: animation, 2d

[image: gre]

I was creating a 2d animation and realized that i wanted to change the color of the strokes later on. I saw a 2.8 tutorial on this but it says that i need to press assign, but there isn't any.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I can drag the "browse material to be linked" icon and drop it on the thing I wanted to change just like in regular 3d materials.

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode and select the object stroke you want to change. Then you will see the <kbd>Assign</kbd> button. Click the button to assign the material. Hope it helps.
[image: screenshot]